# How to generate numbers in range [-1, 1] in c++

Tags: c++

I have to generate numbers in range [-1, 1] in c++. How can I do this with rand if there is only positive numbers available?

Comment: int x = rand() % 2 - 1

Comment: or just use [`std::uniform_real_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

Comment: @Jaan: Evil as some LCGs alternate between odd and even numbers. It also will not draw +1.

Comment: Singhawat thamasaro, integers in the [-1 ... 1] range like [-1,0,1] or floating point values?

Comment: Singhawat thamasaro, If floating point values are needed, do you need to form the edge -1.0, and 1.0 too?

Answer (score -3):

You can use `rand()` function.

```
min_number_in_range + ( std::rand() % ( max_number_in_range - min_number_in_range + 1 ) )
```

Another approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    mt19937 gen(rd()); // seed the generator
    uniform_int_distribution<> distr(-1, 1); // define the range

    cout << distr(gen) << endl; // generate numbers
}
```

Comment: Assuming you want integral drawings, and are happy with the statistical properties of the generator.

Comment: rand() is fraught with issues.

Comment: `( max_number_in_range - min_number_in_range + 1 ) == 3` for max 1 and min -1.